# Can't close custom Web AppBuilder widget programmatically

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am creating a custom widget in ArcGIS Web AppBuilder.

[This page](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/sample-code/close-widget-programmatically.htm) shows how you can use the WidgetManager to close a widget programmatically, saving the user from having to click the X button manually.

The difference between the example code given on the above page and the code in my widget is I have a `declare` portion of my class like so:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'jimu/BaseWidget', 'jimu/WidgetManager', 'dojo/dom-style'],
function(declare, BaseWidget, WidgetManager, style) {
    return declare([BaseWidget], {
        ....
    });
});
```

Within an onClick function in the above, I attempt to call `WidgetManager.getInstance.closeWidget(this.id)`, as recommended by the code sample on the ESRI page. This does not work, and the failure is silent.

I'm a Dojo/Web AppBuilder newbie, but I vaguely  understand that `declare` creates a new instance of a class, whereas the ESRI website seems to be using `WidgetManager` in a more abstract way. Does this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

the first thing that I noticed, is the WidgetManager.getInstance is a **function**, which means you need to call it using

```
WidgetManager.getInstance()
```

I haven't worked with the web app builder yet, but from what I can tell, the WidgetManager is a Singleton class (the class is created once and used throughout the application). Calling the getInstance function of the class returns the `WidgetManager` instance from which you can access its [properties and methods documented in the API](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/api-reference/panelmanager.htm)

As a starting point for debugging, place a

```
console.log('click');
```

in the onClick handler. This will ensure that your function is indeed named and placed correctly.

Next try using the console.log function to make sure you have valid properties. Example:

```
console.log(this.id)
```

Declare doesn't actually create a new instance of a class, it simply "declares" a new class from which a developer can create new instances using something like

```
var widget = new YourWidget({
    property: 'value'
}, "widgetNode");
```

In your case, you are declaring a new class that inherits from the `BaseWidget` class, meaning your class will inherit the functions and properties of the `BaseWidget`.

Hope this helps.